# Adding key-value to Laravel result object/collection

Tags: laravel, collections, model, insert

New to Laravel. Have what seems like should be a non-issue, but is causing a headache.

I'm trying to insert a key-value pair (bookingRef) within the result object/collection returned, such that the result would be:

```
[{"class_id":7,"class_name":"beginner","class_slots_avail":100,"class_slots_booked":53,"class_date":"2020-12-07 21:47:23","class_time":"09:25:00","class_reg_price":350, bookingRef: 127}]
```

I've tried methods such as push, put and merge that will insert the key-value after the object returned, but this is not what I require.

Here is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Models\Booking;

use App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

use DB;

class BookingsController extends Controller
{
    //
    function store(Request $request) {

        $id = $request->input('class');
        
        if(DB::table('classes')->where('class_id', '=', $id)->exists()) {

            if(DB::table('classes')->where('class_id', '=', $id)->value('class_slots_booked') 
            < DB::table('classes')->where('class_id', '=', $id)->value('class_slots_avail')) {
            
                $booking = new Booking();
                
                $booking->class_id = $id;
                $booking->user_id = \Auth::id();
                $booking->save();


                DB::table('classes')->where('class_id', '=', $id)->increment('class_slots_booked', 1);

                if($booking) {


                    $confBook = DB::table('classes')->where('class_id', '=', $id)->get();

                    $confBook->bookingRef = $booking->id;

                    \error_log($confBook);
                }
               
            }
            else return('CLASS FULLY BOOOOKED');
    }
    else return('CLASS NOT Available');
}
}
```

Comment: are there multiple classes with the same `class_id`?

Comment: Lagbox.No, just one.

Comment: as someone else's deleted comment said, you probably want `first()` instead of `get()` there so you get a single record instead of a Collection of them

Comment: would probably be easier if you had a Model for the `classes` table

Comment: Apologies. I should have clarified - I'm using get() so that I can use a foreach loop in the view, which will be used for single and multiple results. If there's a way to get the value into the results using first(), I'd be happy to just make two views.

Comment: can you show the part where you are passing the data to the view

Comment: return view('view-booking', ['bookings' => $confBook]

Answer (score 0):

You can cut down on your queries and put this extra data in place with some adjustments:

```
function store(Request $request)
{
    $id = $rquest->input('class');

    $class = DB::table('classes')->where('class_id', $id)->first();

    if ($class) {
        if ($class->class_slots_booked < $class->class_slots_avail) {
            $booking = new Booking();
            $booking->class_id = $id;
            $booking->user_id = $request->auth()->id;

            if ($booking->save()) {
                // adding the extra data
                $class->bookingRef = $booking->id;

                DB::table('classes')->where('class_id', $id)
                    ->increment('class_slots_booked', 1);

                $class->class_slots_booked++;

                return view('view-booking', [
                    'bookings' => collect($class),
                ]);
            }
            // booking did not save
        }
        // unavailable
    }
    // class not found
}
```

This would be a little more convenient with a Model for the `classes` table and a relationship setup to Booking would be a plus as well.

Comment: Afraid that hasn't worked. Thanks for your help, though.

Comment: @monkeytrick what about it hasn't worked?

Comment: @monkeytrick cool, how did you resolve it?

Comment: lagbox, I've almost replicated your code, save for using a model (also your suggestion) instead of the DB. Do you want to edit to reflect that, and then I'll select that as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve it, thanks to Lagbox's suggestion of using a model:

```
   <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Models\Booking;
use App\Models\Classes;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class BookingsController extends Controller
{
    //
    function store(Request $request) {

        $id = $request->input('class');
        
        $class = Classes::where('class_id', $id)->first();

        if($class) {

            if($class->class_slots_booked < $class->class_slots_avail) {

                 $booking = new Booking();
                
                 $booking->class_id = $id;
                 $booking->user_id = Auth::id();

                 if($booking->save()){

                    $class->where('class_id', $id)->increment('class_slots_booked');
                    $class->bookingRef = $booking->id;

                    return view('view-booking', ['bookings' => $class]);

                 }              
            }
            else return('Class Fully Booked');           

        }
        else return('Class Not Available');

    }
};
```

From what I can see, the get() method returns an array with object(s), which is why object->new_property = value would not work. The first() method, however, seems to return a single object, which is why it would.
Seems I've got some reading up on models and collections to do.

Comment: you can call `$class->increment('class_slots_booked')` since you are using a Model

Comment: seems like the same code just using a model

Comment: langox, It is. See my earlier comment offering to accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, Start with a collection [1, 2, 3]. We use the map method to add 1 to each item in the collection. Then, we use the push method to add a new value 4 to the collection. Finally, we use the all method to retrieve the underlying array representation of the collection.

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3]);

$modifiedCollection = $collection->map(function ($item) {
    // Add 1 to each item in the collection
    return $item + 1;
});

$modifiedCollection->push(4); // Add a new value to the collection

dd($modifiedCollection->all());
```

**The output will be:**

```
[2, 3, 4, 4]
```